# Bind knockout property to length of svg text element

Tags: knockout.js, svg

I want to bind a knockout property to the length of an svg text element so that it is set every time the text is changed. I've started with something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.length = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var width = element.getComputedTextLength();
        valueAccessor()(width);
        element.onchange = function() {
            var newWidth = element.getComputedTextLength();
            valueAccessor()(newWidth);
        };
    }
};
```

and the svg element

```
<text data-bind="text: text, length: labelLength" x="0" y="0" fill="black">Hello World</text>
```

jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/9vWhD/

Any idea of the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the width of an element when the text changes, you can use a computed observable (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vWhD/3/) :

```
var model = function(){
    this.text = ko.observable("Hello World");
    this.labelLength = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.text().length * 10;
    });
    this.changeText = function(){
        this.text("This is some much longer text");
    }
}
```

Or you want to get the width of the text element after the text has been set? If this is the case, you can change the custom binding like this (fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/9vWhD/6/):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textSetLength = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).text(valueAccessor()());
        var width = $(element)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        this.labelLength(width);
    }
};
```